# Post запрос axios vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Хочу отправить значение data_state = false на сервер после клика на картинку.
Код скрипта:

```
 const car = (image) => ({image})
    const cars = [
        car('images/1.jpg'),
        car('images/2.jpg')
    ]
    new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        data_state: true,
        cars,
        car: cars[0]
    },
    methods: {
        change_image: function() {
            this.car = cars[1];
            data_state = false;
        },
        data_state_img() {
            axios.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
                data_state: this.data_state
            })
            .then(response => {})
        }
    }
    })
```

Темплейт:

```
<div id="app">
    <div @change="data_state_img()" v-model="data_state">
        <img
            v-on:click="change_image"
            class="detalied-image pointer"
            :src="car.image" 
        >
    </div>
</div>
```

Пишет ошибку:

```
<div v-model="data_state">: v-model is not supported on this element type. If you are working with contenteditable, it's recommended to wrap a library dedicated for that purpose inside a custom component.
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Вот эта запись `v-on:change` равнозначна этой `@change` и эквивалентна атрибуту событий в нативном JavaScript `onchange`. Подробнее о событии [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).

Answer (score 0):

> v-model использует разные свойства и генерирует разные события для
>   различных **элементов ввода**

[источник](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

Comment: Пожалуйста,если вы цитируете, то указывайте источник.

Comment: А какое свойство нужно для передачи такого элемента?